# re-install system app at /data/app not work at android Oreo(8.0)

Tags: android

I'm want to re-install system app for some update, but when it re-install finish,  i have some Exception error.It tips not find some API implementation.Who can help me to resolve this , very thanks~

Exception Message:

```
 11-01 09:36:28.075  6054  6054 E ConfigDataMng: initPlayerSDK Exception, e: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tencent.qqlive.mediaplayer.api.TVK_SDKMgr
11-01 09:36:28.277  2980  3271 E TvUserSettingProvider: updating content://mstar.tv.usersetting/systemsetting, value = bStrStatus=1
11-01 09:36:28.297  6054  6054 E linker  : library "/vendor/lib64/libtvmanager_jni.so" ("/vendor/lib64/libtvmanager_jni.so") needed or dlopened by "/system/lib64/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for the namespace: [name="classloader-namespace", ld_library_paths="", default_library_paths="/system/fake-libs64:/data/app/com.android.mslauncher--ozeyF0TBbhBzuLP2dULUQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a", permitted_paths="/data:/mnt/expand:/data/data/com.android.mslauncher"]
11-01 09:36:28.298  6054  6054 E zygote64: No implementation found for void com.mstar.android.tvapi.common.TvManager.native_setup(java.lang.Object) (tried Java_com_mstar_android_tvapi_common_TvManager_native_1setup and Java_com_mstar_android_tvapi_common_TvManager_native_1setup__Ljava_lang_Object_2)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.mslauncher, PID: 6054
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.mstar.android.tvapi.common.TvManager.native_setup(java.lang.Object) (tried Java_com_mstar_android_tvapi_common_TvManager_native_1setup and Java_com_mstar_android_tvapi_common_TvManager_native_1setup__Ljava_lang_Object_2)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.mstar.android.tvapi.common.TvManager.native_setup(Native Method)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.mstar.android.tvapi.common.TvManager.<init>(TvManager.java:235)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.mstar.android.tvapi.common.TvManager.getInstance(TvManager.java:214)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.ktc.launcher.utils.DataBaseUtil.setSystemSettingValue(DataBaseUtil.java:82)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.ktc.launcher.activity.LauncherActivity.onCreate(LauncherActivity.java:239)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6978)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
11-01 09:36:28.299  6054  6054 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
```

Comment: The reason is that fater the coverage is installed, the app in the data partition,but the lib API dependent is in the system partition,which cannot be accessed.